# Rails and React return a text only page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I've been trying to include React.js into my Rails app for paginating the `index` page for my `Items` model. I've been following [this example](http://react.rocks/example/rails-and-react) and trying incorporate it into my current project. I've managed to integrate everything to a point that no errors are showing. But now the index page has just turned into text, this text is a representation of `@items` and it gets displayed using the `render` action

items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    # ...
    def index
        @items =
            Kaminari.paginate_array(Item.first(10)).page(params[:page])
        #...
        render json: {
            items: @items,
            meta: {
                current_page: @items.current_page,
                next_page: @items.next_page,
                prev_page: @items.prev_page,
                total_pages: @items.total_pages,
                total_count: @items.total_count
            }
        }
    end
end
```

I do not know why this is happening, I've followed the guide but getting none of the results. I don't even know what code is really going wrong because there isn't any errors coming from it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[Website main page](https://ror-supermarket.herokuapp.com/items), works fine

[Index page for Item model](https://ror-supermarket.herokuapp.com/items), completely text

[Repo for my app](https://github.com/dretta/ROR-SuperMarket), I've left commit message showing what I changed for React

Comment: You know u are render as json?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Json, but yeah it looks like it. However after the `index` action runs, the view should be displayed?

Comment: And I'm not familir with react.js. Now I see the example that use json. But try to change render json: ... to render html: .. to see what happend.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help you more but I am not familir with react.js.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll need to either render an HTML page and then request the data as an Ajax request, or render an HTML page with the data embedded within the page (injected). Right now, you're just rendering the JSON output rather than the page.

Comment: So I render an html page and use an ajax request in `app/views/items/index.html.erb` ?

Comment: By default, your index controller action renders an `index.html.erb` file that is found at `app/views/[controller name minus 'controller']/index.html.erb`. This is part of the Rails magic. You don't have to use 'render' if the action is supposed to render the html template. If you specify `render` like here, though, it's going to override that functionality and render whatever you pass to `render`. In this case,  you are rendering a JSON object, which is just the big blob of text that you're seeing on the page. Do you have a view template at `app/views/items/index.html.erb`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have the proper view template. What do I need to do to manually render `index.html.erb` and the pagination javascript files found in the assets directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "ITems", items_path(format: :json) %>
```

will send a page requesting a json response from your server.  Normally this would be from an ajax request.

```
<%= link_to "ITems", items_path %>
```

however is making an http request. You only have one handler (format.json)that takes the request and happily converts the response to json.  But since your CLIENT requested the response as html, (check your request headers), it dumps the rendered json within the html response

Comment: I'm getting an error:
`Template is missing
Missing template items/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/username/ROR-SuperMarket/app/views" * "/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views" * "/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"`
I'm guessing I don't have a template view for index, how would I get one?